# Installing packages from default environment in venv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv, python-wheel

I created a virtual environment and I'm trying to import packages such as numpy from my default environment to the virtual one. I tried using pip but I can't figure out how to import packages from my local storage.In my case downloading the same packages from the web is not an option.

Comment: Don't import them from another environment. Install them into the virtual environment.

Comment: "In my case downloading the same packages from the web is not an option."—why not?

Comment: Because I don't have connection to the internet on that machine...

Comment: How did you install the packages in question in the first environment?

Comment: if you installed them then they should be available in the local [cache](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/#caching) on your computer